# Pointer-to-Member function in ref class

Tags: .net, function, pointers, c++-cli, member

I am trying to use a custom .NET ref class to control a button system. It consists of a PictureBox inside the class that is added to the parent form. When it detects a click, it needs to call the function specified in the constructor that is a method inside the parent class.

For instance:

```
//in the custom class file
public ref class CButton {
    private: void (*callingproc)(void);
    public:
    CButton(void (*cproc)(void)) {
        callingproc = cproc;
    }
    button_dowork() {
        //do our code to detect if the click was in the right place and call our proc
        callingproc();
    }
};
//in the form.h
void cp(void) {
    //do our form work
}
void Form_CreateCButton() {
    CButton^ t = gcnew CButtom(cp);
}
```

The above causes errors along the lines of "use &ns::form::cp to create a pointer to member", followed by "pointer-to-member not valid for managed class" when I follow the instructions. Any ideas?

Comment: You *must* use a delegate here.  Well covered in any introductory text on C++/CLI programming.

Comment: Retagged from C++ to C++-CLI

Comment: "Well covered in any introductory text on C++/CLI programming" - any chance of a link to this?

Comment: Find some simple examples of making delegates on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c320cx3h.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your class is storing a pointer to a (global) function.

Perhaps your void cp() function is inside a class ("form"?).  In that case, it is actually a member function.  Global functions are different than member functions, so the class can't store the pointer.

Maybe you should consider Delegates (especially if you are using .Net).  See:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379617(v=vs.80).aspx